# Using setter to post notifications as value changes?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

```
- (void) setNeededValue:(valueType)newValue;
{
    neededValue = newValue;

    if( neededValue > threshold )
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"setNeededValue" object: self];
    }
}
```

//////////////////

```
-(void)callfunction{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setNeededValue) name:@"setNeededValue" object:nil];

NSLog(@"sam: %d,100);
}
```

setNeededValue get called and problem exist with the calling Notification? When it reaches threshold condition does it call the function callfunction... :( Bit new to this? Please help me!!

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: What is the problem? One issue is that your addObserver: method is triggering setNeededValue but you are implementing setNeededValue: (0 arguments versus one argument). Even then, notifications that have one argument pass in an NSNotification object, so not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: No idea! When it functions the -(void)callfunction should get call and print 100, But it's not working! :(

Comment: If your callfunction does not get called before threshold is reached, than you failed to register for any Notifications, and you are posting notifications that you did not register for...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that you are setting your self as observer for Notification in a wrong spot.

You become observer for your notification inside callfunction (which gets called when threshold is met).

Observer should be added only once when object or view is instantiated. And removed when it gets removed.

So move the addObserver to your init (or in case you are inside view controller in viewDidLoad method).

As Christian pointed out, this below should not be a problem

*I would replace:
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"setNeededValue" object: self];
with
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"setNeededValue" object: nil];
Then it should work, because Notification center checks object passed from postNotification and looks at the observer and if there is a match it will get called, if not it won't.
In your case you post Notification with object `self`, but in addObserver you have object `nil`*

Comment: It's perfectly fine to post a notification with an object and have an observer use nil. Using nil just means "I am listening for any object that posts the notification, not one specific object"

Comment: Recheck the answer, add your addObserver code in viewDidLoad or init.

Comment: When i called it in viewDidLoad, program stops at 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"setNeededValue" object: nil]; with the error: program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: add the addObserver method to viewDidLoad and not postNotification.

Comment: so add: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setNeededValue) name:@"setNeededValue" object:nil]; to your viewDidLoad

Comment: :O sorry, it's a typing mistake! I get that error when i use [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setNeededValue) name:@"setNeededValue" object:nil];

Comment: You are doing something wrong...I have used this notification declaration inside viewDidLoad in 10's of apps and 100's of files...